# SwiftUI custom mouse pointer on iPadOS

Tags: swift, ipad, swiftui, ipados

How can we have a custom mouse pointer one a view using SwiftUI + iPadOS?

Apple has an example of how to do that in this code but is for UIKit:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/pointer_interactions/enhancing_your_ipad_app_with_pointer_interactions

```
class QuiltView: UIView, UIPointerInteractionDelegate {


...
    


func sharedInit() {
    ...

    // Add a pointer interaction for the "editor" area Quilt view.
    self.addInteraction(UIPointerInteraction(delegate: self))
}

// Supply custom regions that correspond to grid lines when "useStraightLineStitch" is enabled.
func pointerInteraction(_ interaction: UIPointerInteraction,
                        regionFor request: UIPointerRegionRequest,
                        defaultRegion: UIPointerRegion) -> UIPointerRegion? {
    if useStraightLineStitch {
        let regionNumber = floor(request.location.y / gridHeight)
        return UIPointerRegion(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: regionNumber * gridHeight, width: self.bounds.size.width, height: gridHeight))
    } else {
        return defaultRegion
    }
}

// Supply pointer style with custom crosshair shape.
func pointerInteraction(_ interaction: UIPointerInteraction, styleFor region: UIPointerRegion) -> UIPointerStyle? {
    let crosshair = UIPointerShape.path(crosshairBezierPath())

    if useStraightLineStitch {
        return UIPointerStyle(shape: crosshair, constrainedAxes: [.vertical])
    } else {
        return UIPointerStyle(shape: crosshair)
    }
}

func crosshairBezierPath() -> UIBezierPath {
    let crosshairPath = UIBezierPath()
    crosshairPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: -1.5, y: 1.5))
    crosshairPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: -1.5, y: 10))
    crosshairPath.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 10),
                         radius: 1.5,
                         startAngle: CGFloat.pi,
                         endAngle: 0,
                         clockwise: false)
    crosshairPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 1.5, y: 1.5))
    crosshairPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 10, y: 1.5))
    crosshairPath.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: 10, y: 0),
                         radius: 1.5,
                         startAngle: CGFloat.pi / 2.0,
                         endAngle: CGFloat.pi * 1.5,
                         clockwise: false)
    crosshairPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 1.5, y: -1.5))
    crosshairPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 1.5, y: -10))
    crosshairPath.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: 0, y: -10),
                         radius: 1.5,
                         startAngle: 0,
                         endAngle: CGFloat.pi,
                         clockwise: false)
    crosshairPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: -1.5, y: -1.5))
    crosshairPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: -10, y: -1.5))
    crosshairPath.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: -10, y: 0),
                         radius: 1.5,
                         startAngle: CGFloat.pi * 1.5,
                         endAngle: CGFloat.pi / 2.0,
                         clockwise: false)
    crosshairPath.close()
    return crosshairPath
}


...
```

}

What I'm looking for is to achieve the same but using SwiftUI?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do this with Apple's current APIs, I don't believe that is something you can do. Hopefully such a feature will come in a future release.

However, you can still enable this feature by doing some Introspection.

First, a **warning**: While common UIKit elements back SwiftUI views on iOS, this is not guaranteed to be true in all cases. Therefore, this solution may break at some point in the future.

Now, to a possible approach.

Add an introspection package to your app. In the past, I have used [SwiftUI-Introspect](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect) (to add a `UIDropInteraction` to my views). Then import the `Introspect` module into your source file.

Most introspect packages, such as this one, include `View` extensions that let you examine the underlying UIKit components. Depending on what your view is, you'll use a specific modifier.

For instance, if you want to get the underlying view controller for a specific view, you would use the `.introspectViewController()` modifier. You provide it a closure that will be given the view controller. You can add your interaction to the view controller's view. (If you have a scroll view, use the `introspectScrollView` modifier, etc)

Example, assuming a class named `PointerDelegate` that conforms to `UIPointerInteractionDelegate`:

```
import SwiftUI
import Introspect

struct YourView: View {

  var body: some View {
    // Your view hierarchy
    // For instance
    List { ... }
      .introspectViewController { viewController in 
        viewController.view.addInteraction(UIPointerInteraction(delegate: PointerDelegate()))
      }
  }
}
```

This is a bit of a hack, and as warned earlier may break in the future. However, this is a way to gain access to some features that are only enabled in UIKit from within your SwiftUI apps.

Comment: Hey Josh thank you for your suggestion, your suggestion is really interesting but it didn't work for me using UIPointerInteraction. 
Maybe a possible way to go is to use UIViewRepresentable functionality, but I still, need to learn a little about this.

Comment: @TiagoMendes Trying this out this morning, a couple of comments: (1) You need to persist your delegate. Making it a singleton and passing that into the `UIPointerInteraction(delegate:)` call should work. (2) Unless you are adding this to something specific in UIKit, like a UITextField or UITableView, it's hard to introspect this. If you just look for a UIView, you can easily end up with the wrong view, or a view with no width/height.

Comment: I am marking your answer as correct, your solution worked +/- . Whenever I click the cursor disappears and the circle goes back and in some elements, it only shows the circle. But it's better to have this than to have nothing. Thank you very much for your response + time and let's hope that the SwiftUI team give support to this :D

Comment: You're welcome! I'm glad it was able to help you out. I, too, hope more of this functionality comes natively to SwiftUI.